# `' '.join(e)` isn't changing value of e

Tags: python

I'm creating a function to create all 26 combinations of words with a fixed suffix. The script works except for the JOIN in the second-to-last line.

```
def create_word(suffix):
    e=[]
    letters="abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    t=list(letters)
    for i in t:
        e.append(i)
        e.append(suffix)
    ' '.join(e)
    print e
```

Currently, it is printing `['a', 'suffix', 'b', 'suffix, ...etc]`. And I want it to print out as one long string: `'aSuffixbSuffixcSuffix...etc.'` Why isn't the join working in this? How can I fix this?

In addition, how would I separate the characters once I have the string? For example to translate "take the last character of the suffix and add a space to it every time ('aSuffixbSuffixcSuffix' --> 'aSuffix bSuffix cSuffix')". Or, more generally, to replace the x-nth character, where x is any integer (e.g., to replace the 3rd, 6th, 9th, etc. character some something I choose).

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by "taking the last character of the suffix and adding a space to it every time", along with your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.join` returns the new value, not transform the existing one.  Here's one way to accomplish it.

```
result = ' '.join(e)
print result
```

But if you're feeling clever, you can streamline a lot of the setup.

```
import string
def create_word(suffix):
   return ' '.join(i + suffix for i in string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to the punch :)

Answer (score 0):

join doesn't change its arguments - it just returns a new string:

```
result = ' '.join(e)
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the output you specified (all of the results concatenated together):

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> letters = string.ascii_lowercase
>>> suffix = 'Suffix'
>>> ''.join('%s%s' % (l, suffix) for l in letters)
'aSuffixbSuffixcSuffixdSuffixeSuffixfSuffixgSuffixhSuffixiSuffixjSuffixkSuffixlSuffixmSuffixnSuffixoSuffixpSuffixqSuffixrSuffixsSuffixtSuffixuSuffixvSuffixwSuffixxSuffixySuffixzSuffix'
```

Answer (score -1):

Beside the problem already mentioned by rekursive, you should have a look at list comprehension:

```
def create_word(suffix):
    return ''.join(
        [i+suffix for i in "abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]
    )
print create_word('suffix')
```