# Separating a string in Python

Tags: python

How would I separate characters once I have a string of unseparated words?

For example to translate "take the last character of the suffix and add a space to it every time (`"aSuffixbSuffixcSuffix"` --> `"aSuffix bSuffix cSuffix"`).`

Or, more generally, to replace the x-nth character, where x is any integer (e.g., to replace the 3rd, 6th, 9th, etc. character some something I choose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the replace method of strings. Check [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.replace)

```
initial = "aSuffixbSuffixcSuffix"

final = initial.replace("Suffix", "Suffix ")
print(final)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're getting your string from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641090/python-join-list-question), the easiest way is to not cram all the strings together in the first place. Your original `create_word` could be changed to this:

```
def create_word(suffix):
    letters="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    return [i + suffix for i in letters]
```

Then you'd be able to take `e` and `''.join(e)` or `' '.join(e)` to get the strings you want.

Comment: Did you mean to miss out the letter `d` from `letters`?

Comment: @Luke Probably not. I copied that line from the question in the link, but fixed anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
   str = "SuffixbSuffixcSuffix"

   def chunk_str(str, chunk_size):
        return [str[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(str), chunk_size)]

   " ".join(chunk_str(str,3))
```

returns:

```
'Suf fix bSu ffi xcS uff ix'
```